# Current pending sector count error

Tags: linux, debian, badblocks, smart

Recently my hard disk show some error message in *SMART* utility, I have taken a screenshot from error messages. That's something like : *Current pending sector count error* && *Relocated sector count* . Can someone explain me how to fix such Bad Sector and Errors ?

[image]

[image]

notice : Sometimes system hangout and syslog show "*Kernel:Journal commit I/O error*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to fix these bad sectors and to get rid of the warnings is by backing up, replacing the hardware and restoring (if the drive is part of a RAID-5, you should just swap the drive and let the RAID software reconstruct the contents).

Although you could get rid of the problems with these sectors by remapping (or having the drive remap them for you if it is smart enough), that doesn't take away the cause for the problems. For me these error counts are to high to trust the system to continue working.

Comment: Thank you,I replace my HDD hardware.After wasting lot time around way to resolving issue. ;)